# Sort a list in Racket based on the operator

Tags: list, merge, racket, plai

How can I sort and merge two lists based on the operator in Racket-Plait? > ascending, < descending order.  This is what I have so far, but I do not have any idea what to do next.

```
(define (merge [op : (Number Number -> Boolean)]
               [int-list1 : (Listof Number)]
               [int-list2 : (Listof Number)]) : (Listof Number)
  (cond
    [(equal? op <) "something"]
    [(equal? op >) "do something"])) 

(test (merge < '(1 4 6) '(2 5 8))
      '(1 2 4 5 6 8))
```

Comment: If this is homework, could you add the exact instructions? Which parts of your code are included in the instructions (so the solution should include them) and which are yours?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're assuming that this is more complicated than it is.

You're not supposed to do different things depending on the value of `op` - `op` is the ordering predicate you should use for merging and the predicate that the input lists are ordered by.
(In contrast to many other languages, symbols like `<` or `>` are not "special" in any way, they are identifiers just like `less`, or `greater`, or `op`)

Here is a skeleton special case to get you started; the interesting bits are left as an exercise:

```
(define (merge [l1 : (Listof Number)]
               [l2 : (Listof Number)]) : (Listof Number)
  (cond [(empty? l1) l2]  ;; If either list is empty,
        [(empty? l2) l1]  ;; the result is the other list.
        [(< (first l1) (first l2)) ... fill this in ...]
        [else ... fill this in ...]))
```

then, notice that this is equivalent to the code above:

```
(define op <)

(define (merge [l1 : (Listof Number)]
               [l2 : (Listof Number)]) : (Listof Number)
  (cond [(empty? l1) l2]  ;; If either list is empty,
        [(empty? l2) l1]  ;; the result is the other list.
        [(op (first l1) (first l2)) ... fill this in ...]
        [else ... fill this in ...]))
```

and then you pass `op` as a parameter instead, and you're done.